# Connect k8s pod to iscsi

Tags: kubernetes, iscsi

I'm using a terastation's iscsi capabilities to create storage for my k8s 1.14 cluster (kubeadm, ubuntu 18.04).  I check the iqn:

```
iscsiadm --mode node
192.168.2.113:3260,1 iqn.2004-08.jp.buffalo.7403bd2a30a0.drupal-mysql
```

There's no ":".  when I try to use

```
volumes:
    - name: iscsi-data
      iscsi:
        targetPortal: 192.168.2.113:3260
        iqn: "iqn.2004-08.jp.buffalo.7403bd2a30a0.drupal-mysql"
        lun: 0
        fsType: xfs
```

i get the error:

```
spec.template.spec.volumes[0].iscsi.iqn: Invalid value: "iqn.2004-08.jp.buffalo.7403bd2a30a0.drupal-mysql": must be valid format
```

i know its looking for something that ends in a ":name" but I can't figure out what thats supposed to be for the life of me.  I know the iscsi drive mounts because i can see it on my node and was able to format it using xfs.  I think I'm missing something really simple.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

[iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI#Addressing) network storage standard is fully documented in [RFC 3720](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3720) and  [RFC 3721](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3721) with an appropriate IQN constructing format for iSCSI names.

iSCSI qualified name (IQN), coressponds to the following form:

> **iqn.yyyy-mm.naming-authority:unique-name**, where:
>
> **iqn** – the prefix iqn.
>
> **yyyy-mm** – the year and month when the naming authority was established. For example: 1992-08.
>
> **naming-authority** – the organizational naming authority string, usually reverse syntax of the Internet domain name of the naming
> authority. For example: com.vmware.
>
> **unique name** – any name you want to use, such as the name of your host. For example: host-1

In the above k8s volume spec case you might try to specify IQN like:

`iqn: "iqn.2004-08.jp.buffalo:7403bd2a30a0.drupal-mysql"`

Find some relative example about iSCSI volume provisioning in k8s cluster [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_iscsi.html).

Comment: Give a try with above solution, in case of any doubts or upcoming issues edit your initial question.